# Azure CLI fails on `az component update`

Tags: python, azure, command-line-interface, azure-cli

After running `az component update`, I get the following error:

```
$ az component update
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 1.5MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.8MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 4.1MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 4.8MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 4.5MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 808kB 1.5MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 8.9MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 5.1MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 3.7MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 245kB 4.2MB/s 
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 399kB 2.5MB/s 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/59/qls0d_2n2h5g9683fqp5ltl40000gn/T/pip-build-K4RCxY/azure-cli-core/azure/cli/core/telemetry_upload.py", line 10, in <module>
    import azure.cli.core.decorators as decorators
ImportError: No module named azure.cli.core.decorators
```

Subsequently, calls to `az` fail.

```
$ az
/Users/user/lib/azure-cli/bin/python: No module named azure
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest changes introduce a break in the `az component` command.  Just reinstall from scratch (settings, etc. will be preserved): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli.

```
$ curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

If the CLI was installed with `pip` the command below fixes the environment.

`pip install --force-reinstall --upgrade azure-nspkg azure-mgmt-nspkg`

Alternatively if the CLI was installed in a virtual environment, delete the environment, create a new one and install the CLI again.